# Android Studio AlarmManager is not running at the specific time

Tags: android, alarm

This is the code for the alarm manager:

```
protected void alarmInit(){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 25);

    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, SampleBootReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, alarmIntent, 0);

    manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

This is the Broadcast class:

```
    public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                intent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        context)
                        // Set Icon
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icono)
                        // Set Ticker Message
                        .setTicker("message")
                        // Set Title
                        .setContentTitle("asdf")
                        // Set Text
                        .setContentText("message")
                        // Add an Action Button below Notification
                        // Set PendingIntent into Notification
                        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                        // Dismiss Notification
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

                // Create Notification Manager
                NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                // Build Notification with Notification Manager
                notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But at the set time I do not receive any message (I don't see the Toast message with the word Hello).
Also, in Manifest XML I set inside aplication tag:

```
<receiver android:name=".Home$SampleBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="false"
        tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
```

The class SampleBootReceiver is a public class in Home class

Could you please help me with this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are using `setInexactRepeating` so the OS will decide when to fire your alarm. The OS tries to group together alarms to save battery.

> Beginning with API 19 (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) alarm delivery is
> inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and
> battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need
> strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long,
> android.app.PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long,
> android.app.PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is
> earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in
> which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Comment: Thanks but the code never runs. I think there is something wrong in the code.